# MySQL Workbench, average of NULL is returning "0", I need it to return NULL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-null

I am trying to average my plot level data. When I perform my query on a plot level, it results in "NULL" for all rows associated with some line names. When I perform the same query attempting to AVG the traits and group by line name, the result shows "0". I need it to show "NULL" so it does not affect my grand mean.

Example code to select plot-level data:

```
SELECT experiment_name, `year`, location_name, line_name, head_dap, height_cm, yield_bua
FROM data_amba
WHERE experiment_name = 'matspr' AND `year` = 2018 AND location_name = 'Stephen'
GROUP BY line_name, head_dap, height_cm, yield_bua;
```

Results:

```
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| line_name  | head_dap | height_cm | yield_bua |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| ND_GENESIS | NULL     | NULL      | 130.9     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| ND_GENESIS | NULL     | NULL      | 131.3     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| ND_GENESIS | NULL     | NULL      | 134.3     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| PINNACLE   | NULL     | NULL      | 144.9     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| PINNACLE   | NULL     | NULL      | 146.6     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| PINNACLE   | NULL     | NULL      | 163.9     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M177     | NULL     | NULL      | 107.6     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M177     | NULL     | NULL      | 142.6     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M177     | NULL     | NULL      | 168.6     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M178     | NULL     | NULL      | 114.6     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M178     | NULL     | NULL      | 132.9     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M178     | NULL     | NULL      | 154.6     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M179     | NULL     | NULL      | 132.6     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M179     | NULL     | NULL      | 137.9     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M179     | NULL     | NULL      | 140.6     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M180     | NULL     | NULL      | 101.9     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M180     | NULL     | NULL      | 147.3     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M180     | NULL     | NULL      | 169.6     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M181     | NULL     | NULL      | 111.9     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M181     | NULL     | NULL      | 125.3     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| S2M181     | NULL     | NULL      | 138.9     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Example code to select averages:

```
SELECT experiment_name, `year`, location_name, line_name, AVG(head_dap), AVG(height_cm), AVG(yield_bua)
FROM data_amba
WHERE experiment_name = 'matspr' AND `year` = 2018 AND location_name = 'Stephen'
GROUP BY line_name;
```

Results:

```
+------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| line_name  | AVG(head_dap) | AVG(height_cm) | AVG(yield_bua) |
+------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| ND_GENESIS | 0             | 0              | 132.1667       |
+------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| PINNACLE   | 0             | 0              | 151.8          |
+------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| S2M177     | 0             | 0              | 139.6          |
+------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| S2M178     | 0             | 0              | 134.0333       |
+------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| S2M179     | 0             | 0              | 137.0333       |
+------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| S2M180     | 0             | 0              | 139.6          |
+------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| S2M181     | 0             | 0              | 125.3667       |
+------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
```

When 3 "NULL" values are averaged, I expect to see "NULL" in the results rather than "0" so it does not affect any grand mean calculations I perform downstream.

Comment: Have you tried a different client? Do you get the same results?

Comment: AVG in MySQL is expected to average only non-NULLs, so unless you have one zero in there, you should *never* get 0 in your scenario. If the **only** case in which you expect NULL is when you have all NULLs - this means you only expect to ever average **strictly positive** numbers - then use `NULLIF(AVG(), 0)`. Otherwise you'll have to build complicated workarounds using `SUM(IF(...))/COUNT(IF(...))` and manage corner cases in which you might find yourself dividing by 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest workaround that I can think of is using NULLIF function -

```
SELECT experiment_name
      ,`year`
      ,location_name
      ,line_name
      ,NULLIF(AVG(head_dap), 0)
      ,NULLIF(AVG(height_cm), 0)
      ,NULLIF(AVG(yield_bua), 0)
FROM data_amba
WHERE experiment_name = 'matspr'
AND `year` = 2018
AND location_name = 'Stephen'
GROUP BY line_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be the **behavior** of MySQL WorkBench to show zero for integer field.When I run the same in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), It's shows *null* in case if *all the rows are null* belonging to the category.